# Heroku con .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, heroku

Por favor ayúdenme con este problema. Subí un proyecto en heroku utilizando MVC en PHP pero, no funciona correctamente debido a que no lee archivos .htaccess  la cual me permite configurar la url amigables quiero saber si se puede configurar heroku para que acepten este tipos de archivo o como hacer url amigable en heroku. Gracias.

Comment: Tienes instalado el buildpack de apache2? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings

Comment: Hola Junior, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta para evitar sea cerrada**, saludos!

Comment: Encontraste la solución? estoy buscando lo mismo